# How to save string in Unity using BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to save a color string but I always see this error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   ProblemSpecificCompiler.runCSSCompiler (UnityEngine.UI.Button button) (at Assets/Scripts/ProblemSpecificCompiler.cs:2421)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall`1[UnityEngine.UI.Button].Invoke (UnityEngine.UI.Button args0) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:206)
>   UnityEngine.Events.CachedInvokableCall`1[UnityEngine.UI.Button].Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:344)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:65)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:45)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

this is my code in ProblemSpecificCompiler()

```
CSS1Data.css1Control.color2 = colorSave;
CSS1Data.css1Control.Save ();
```

and this is my code in CSS1Data()

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class CSS1Data : MonoBehaviour {

    public static CSS1Data css1Control;


    /*public string color1 = "black";
    public string align1 = "left";
    public string transform1 = "";
    public int fontsize1 = 46;

    public string color2 = "black";
    public string align2 = "left";
    public string transform2 = "";
    public int fontsize2 = 26;*/

    public int test;

    public string color1 = "a";
    public string align1;
    public string transform1;
    public int fontsize1;

    public string color2;
    public string align2;
    public string transform2;
    public int fontsize2;

    void Awake () {
        if (css1Control == null) {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
            css1Control = this;
        }else if(css1Control != this){
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }

        Load ();

    }

    public void Save(){

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/css1Data.dat");

        CSS1DATA data = new CSS1DATA ();

        data.test = test;

        data.color1 = color1;
        data.align1 = align1;
        data.transform1 = transform1;
        data.fontsize1 = fontsize1;

        data.color2 = color2;
        data.align2 = align2;
        data.transform2 = transform2;
        data.fontsize2 = fontsize2;

        bf.Serialize (file,data);
        file.Close ();
    }

    public void Load(){
        if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/css1Data.dat")) {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
            FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/css1Data.dat", FileMode.Open);
            CSS1DATA data = (CSS1DATA)bf.Deserialize (file);
            file.Close ();

            test = data.test;

            color1 = data.color1;
            align1 = data.align1;
            transform1 = data.transform1;
            fontsize1 = data.fontsize1;

            data.color2 = color2;
            data.align2 = align2;
            data.transform2 = transform2;
            data.fontsize2 = fontsize2;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
class CSS1DATA{

    public int test;

    public string color1 = "a";
    public string align1;
    public string transform1;
    public int fontsize1;

    public string color2;
    public string align2;
    public string transform2;
    public int fontsize2;
}
```

What am I missing here? I followed a tutorial in Unity where it saves int and I just tried to save using string

Comment: I think css1Control is null.

Comment: Any suggestion on how can I fix it? @jdweng

Comment: CSS1Data css1Control = new CSS1Data();

Comment: You need to print what is null. Is it css1Control? The log shows you are using a button to call on this. Is the CSS1Data component attached? Is it active?